# Classifying text as emails or ages

Tags: machine-learning, python, multilabel-classification, text-classification

I am trying to classify small strings into three categories.

Examples:

```
X(str column)                    y(str column)
abcd@gmail.com                   email_address
32                               age
@sadn                            invalid(since this is not a valid email address)
1234                             invalid(since this is not a valid age)
```

I am wondering which ML model needs to be used to achieve this case. And also what kind of text processing techniques need to be applied.

Comment: Do you only have emails and age in your X data?

Comment: As of now. It's only emails and age. This could also extent to name, account number etc

Answer (score 1):

You can start with rule-based methods, such as a combination of regular expression and if/then statements.